Liminf, Limsup criterion
I have the following defintion of limsup, liminf in terms of subsequences:

E := {x ∈ R :  there exists a subsequence ($x_{nk}$ ) of the general sequence ($x_n$) such that $x_{nk}$ converges to x}, then $\limsup x_n$ = $\sup E$.

In the case for ($x_n$) bounded, how would one deduce that there is a subsequence that converges to $\limsup x_n$, i.e. that the maximum is attained on E ?

Presumably you mean $x_{n_k}?$

It suffices to show that $\limsup x_n$ can be approximated arbitrarily close. For this, first approximate $\sup E$ by some $a \in E$ then approximate $a$ by an element of the sequence $(x_n)$.

@ShyamR. Thanks, this is sufficent as an answer for me.
